# How to use the unix command "sort" with user-defined collation list?

Tags: sort, macos, locale

Background:

1. The kanji ideograph character sorting / encoding sequence in GB2312, GB18030-2005, GBK, Big5, CNS-11643 varies and are different to how they get sorted in Unicode (incl. UTF-8).
2. As of macOS 12, the `sort` command shipped in macOS never respects the encoding sequence of GB18030 / CNS-11643 / Big5 even if `LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.GB18030 (or zh_TW.Big5, etc.)` is correctly specified.

Minimal working example: Adding this shell command to your macOS Automator app, sending the contents to `stdin`:

```
iconv -t gb18030 | LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.GB18030 sort -uf | iconv -f gb18030
```

[image: Automator command]

(You can bundle a hotkey to this Automator Service through macOS System Preferences.)

After that, create a text document in BBEdit or TextEdit or CotEdit... whatever app you like as long as it supports macOS "services", then copying the following contents into it:

```
一
䴘
```

And you select these two lines, run the Service you created above.

**Expected result**: "一" is sorted above "䴘" as what specified in GB18030.

**Actual result**:  invalid data error.

---

I am going to send this feature enhancement request to Apple, but no one could guarantee whether this feedback will be accepted and dealt. Meanwhile, is there any way of customizing my own collation list to let the `sort` command work as I expect?

Comment: Is your text actually encoded as GB18030?

Comment: @tripleee No. UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @tripleee However, in the minimal example I provided, I have no way to control the encoding used by macOS for handling the clipboard and the text editor.

Comment: Then the real problem here is "garbage in, garbage out", isn't it?

Comment: I said I have no way to control the encoding used by macOS for handling the clipboard and the text editor. I appreciate that your response only solved my doubts regarding how to handle the contents written in ext files, though not related to the minimal working example here.

Comment: But then that's not a "working example" by definition, and the proper solution would be `iconv -t gb18030 | LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.GB18030 sort -uf | iconv -f gb18030`(except round-trip conversion with `iconv` does not seem to work in this scenario, probably because there's a BOM in there somewhere?)

Comment: Also, just `GB18030` isn't a valid value for `LC_ALL`, is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132840/discussion-between-shiki-suen-and-tripleee).